# Why are my cross site cookies not working?

Tags: web, cookies, fetch, samesite

I have been working on a uni project and I'm getting really stuck on why the cross site authentication cookie from our backend isn't set when I do a CORS request to it from our backend.

Our setup is as follows:

A frontend on `https://frontend-domain.com` sends a CORS request to `https://backend-domain.com` with credentials in the post body, expecting a `Set-Cookie: auth-token` header in the response, if credentials are correct.

The fetch to the backend has `credentials: 'include'` set.
The backend response includes `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and explicitly states `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://frontend-domain.com`. The Allowed Methods header is also correct.
The token cookie in the Set-Cookie header has the attributes `SameSite=None`and `Secure`, it's domain attribute is `Domain=backend-domain.com`.

As far as I could find on the mozilla docs or here on stack overflow, these are all the requirements for cross site cookies to work. I expected the Set-Cookie header would make the browser set the cookie, which would then be sent along with all further requests to `https://backend-domain.com`, given `credentials: 'include'` is set.

However, the cookie is never set.

Can anyone help me? I am absolutely clueless by now.

Thank you very much for reading and helping!

**Edit**

I am using Firefox right now.

Here is a screenshot of the request:

[image: request]

And here is the response:

[image: response]

All of the Set-Cookie headers you can see in the response dont result in an actual cookie.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen so the use of `SameSite=None` and the Allow-Credentials header is only for cookies that had been set on `backend-domain.com` in a same site context before?

Comment: @age992 Unless I'm missing something, you're correct in thinking that subsequent requests should carry the cookie in question. Could you edit your question and add a screenshot of the response in your browser's Network tab? Side comment: you only need to set the `Domain` attribute to `backend-domain.com` if you want the cookie to be carried by subsequent requests to _subdomains of `backend-domain.com`_.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Even if the request is cross-origin, if the server responds with the right ACAO header and ACAC: true, the browser should honour the `Set-Cookie` header. Besides, `SameSite=None` does not just affect navigation requests.

Comment: Third-party cookie restrictions cannot be circumvented with headers. That would be an advertisers' dream.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen If you're referring to third-party cookie policies that go beyond SameSite, yes, you're right. I wonder what browser the OP uses...

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers. I added two screenshots of the request and response headers.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen but I wonder, if it's true that third party cookies isn't a thing at all, what do I need the SameSite attribute for, if it only applies to requests "within" one top level domain? Isn't it already possible to restrict cookies to a subdomain / all subdomains of one top level domain via the Domain attribute?

Comment: does this mean an "official" source like the mdn web docs is incorrect? correct me if I'm wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#values Here they state for "Lax": `Cookies are not sent on normal cross-site subrequests ... but are sent when a user is navigating to the origin site.` ... and for "None": `Cookies will be sent in all contexts, i.e. in responses to both first-party and cross-site requests....` Given the distinction between "subrequests" and "navigation" at the "Lax" section, "all contexts" clearly seems to include fetch requests aswell.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen How would you define "navigation requests"? Do you mean "navigation" as [_safe_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Safe/HTTP)?

Comment: I hope my answer ties it together properly.

Answer (score 2):

The `SameSite` attribute of a cookie controls whether this cookie is included in

- subrequests (such as the ones made by an `<img>` or `<iframe>` element or a Javascript `fetch` command) to a different site
- top-level [navigation requests](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#navigation-request) (which load a new page into the current or a new browser tab).

Details are given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#values). Note especially the subtly different treatment of navigation with GET and POST ("Lax-Allowing-Unsafe").

Cookies in subrequests (but not top-level navigation requests) may be *additionally* restricted based on browser settings if they are third-party cookies, that is, if the [registrable domains](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#host-registrable-domain) of their origin and the sending web page differ. In other words: Cookies from `backend-domain.com` count as third-party cookies when a request is made by an HTML page from `frontend-domain.com`, and this is what caused the issue in your case.

Finally, note that same-site is a different concept than same-origin, see the warning and the examples [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#same-site).

Comment: thank you! Do you mean by "may be additionally restricted based on browser settings" that the issue of my case was due to browser specific behavior, that is "out of scope" of the documentation on mozilla.org? Unfortunately, this issue still existed, even after we managed to place our backend and frontend under a common toplevel domain: the fetch requests went from backend.domain.com to frontend.domain.com... but still no cookie was set. We had to move our auth token into the post headers instead to make it work, which unfortunately is a bit less safe since it cannot happen httpOnly.

Comment: "Based on browser settings" means that you can influence the blocking of third-party cookies in the browser settings. `backend.domain.com` and `frontend.domain.com` should not lead to third-party cookies, _unless_ `domain.com` is on the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat). Can you update your question with the latest problem that you observed?